# Per-subsection figure numbering

Tags: sectioning, floats, numbering

I want to have per-subsection figure numbering in the appendix of the following MWE: it should read "Figure A.1" instead of "Figure 2".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{figurewithin=section}

\newcommand*{\appheading}[1][Appendix]{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}\section{#1}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
  \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}  
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo} 

\begin{equation}
  x = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{foo}
  \caption{Fooo}
\end{figure}

\appheading
\appendix
\subsection{Baz}

\begin{equation}
  y = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{baz}
  \caption{Baz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried changing the `thefigure` counter and also using the `chngcntr` package but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Something like this should do what you want.
`\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Figure \Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}`

Comment: `figurewithin=section` should be directly passed to the `caption` package, i.e. `\usepackage[figurewithin=section]{caption}` or `\captionsetup{figurewithin=section}` (without the `[figure]` stuff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\numberwithin` instead of the `figurewithin` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\newcommand*{\appheading}[1][Appendix]{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}\section{#1}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
  \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
  \numberwithin{figure}{subsection}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo} 

\begin{equation}
  x = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{foo}
  \caption{Fooo}
\end{figure}

\appheading
\appendix
\subsection{Baz}

\begin{equation}
  y = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{baz}
  \caption{Baz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Why don't you use `\part*` instead of those tricks?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\newcommand*{\appheading}[1][Appendix]{%
  \part*{#1}
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo} 

\begin{equation}
  x = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{foo}
  \caption{Fooo}
\end{figure}

\appheading
\appendix
\section{Baz}

\begin{equation}
  y = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{baz}
  \caption{Baz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't use part because: (i) with the tricks I can control pdf bookmarks easily (allowing them to go straight to the section heading) (ii) I like the appendix to be a section rather than a part.  Excellent answer BTW. It never ceases to amaze me how much you know about TeX.

Answer (score 3):

insert these two lines immediately after the line `\subsction{Baz}`:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{section}{1}
```